# Tagging: C++ vs C

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I've noticed more and more questions recently having their posts tagged with C++ both [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c).  A couple examples that I have recently handled myself:

- [Karatsuba C++ implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64679/27623)
- [Passing objects to functions safely and efficiently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64723/27623)

As these questions stand, they will not compile as vanilla C code even though they may have a similar syntax and only minor porting changes would have to be made.

**Am I wrong to remove the [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag from these posts?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I cannot see how a post can be tagged with both [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) on Code Review, other than an intentional polyglot.

In terms of [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), if a person writes the code in a C style and compiles it with C++ then it is a C++ question, because *Answers* can then use C++ features as part of the recommendation. If C++ related suggestions are not 'OK' for the question, then it should not be tagged with [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and it should not be **compiled** with C++.

The reverse is also true. Even though people who know C++ may be able to help a [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)-tagged question, then it should still be tagged [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) because it will be compiled with C.

A question writing C++ style and compiled with C is not possible.

A question writing C style and compiled with C++ is possible, but only as a compatibility layer, and is not essentially being compiled as C++

So, a question needs to choose their compiler as part of the tagging, rather than just the style of the code.